# Clicking on button in iframe in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, e-commerce, e2e, cypress-iframe

Ran into the issue, where the test code should click the button Process in the iframe. Used `npm i cypress-iframe lib`, but came up to nothing. Cypress could not find the button.

Tried `cy.iframe('[class="resp-iframe"]').find('resp-iframe[id="submit"]')`

[HTML of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk9mS.png)

Tried the other ways to click on iframe button:

```js
cy.get('iframe[class="resp-iframe"]').then($element => {
             const $body = $element.contents().find('body')
             cy.wrap($body).find('resp-iframe[class="btn btn-block btn-primary"]').eq(0).click();
         })
```

also

```js
cy.get('[class="resp-iframe"]').then($element => {
            const $body = $element.contents().find('body')
            let stripe = cy.wrap($body)
            stripe.find('[class="resp-iframe"]').click(150,150)
          })
```

and

```js
cy.iframe('#resp-iframe').find('[name="submitButton"]')
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McB6C.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otLf5.png)

Updated FYI:
The first part of code - clicking the Google button in bottom-right:

```
const getIframeBody = () => {
            // get the iframe > document > body
            // and retry until the body element is not empty
            return cy
            .get('[id="popup-contentIframe"]')
            .its('0.contentDocument.body')
            // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
            // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
            // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
            .then(cy.wrap)
          }
getIframeBody().find('[id="payWithout3DS"]').click()
```

[image: First step]

Then, waiting for secure payment preloader to finish up:

```
cy.wait(20000)
```

[image: Preloader]

Then, trying to catch the Process button by suggestions:

[image: Secure page]

```
cy.iframe('[name="AcsFrame"]').find('#submit').click()
```

or

```
cy.iframe('[class="resp-iframe"]').find('[id="submit"]')
```

whole code part looks:

```
const getIframeBody = () => {
            // get the iframe > document > body
            // and retry until the body element is not empty
            return cy
            .get('[id="popup-contentIframe"]')
            .its('0.contentDocument.body')
            // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
            // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
            // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
            .then(cy.wrap)
          }
      getIframeBody().find('[id="payWithout3DS"]').click()
      cy.wait(20000)
      cy.iframe('[name="AcsFrame"]').find('#submit').click()
```

But still, getting:

[image: First attempt]
[image: Second attempt]

Maybe anyone had something like that?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Updated with the screenshots in the post.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this:

```js
cy.iframe('[name="AcsFrame"]').find('#submit').click()
```

Comment: Updated the post FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat the `resp-iframe` inside the `.find()`.

The selector `.find('resp-iframe[id="submit"]')` means look for HTML like this: `<resp-iframe id="submit">` but the element you want is `<input id="submit">`.

Everything else looks ok

```js
cy.iframe('[class="resp-iframe"]').find('[id="submit"]')
```

Comment: Updated the post FYI.